# Is there a way to build cross platform desktop application (Mac/Windows) to take care of printing jobs?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, printing, desktop-application

I wanted to know if there's a way to build a cross platform desktop application to take care of printing jobs like able to connect to printer, get notified when printing has started, how many pages got printed, has printing finished, handle their printing queue. I am new to desktop applications, I am not sure of how to begin designing it and whether it's even possible to do so keeping it cross platform.

Comment: Yes there is...

Comment: Okay, Can you explain me how can we do it?

Comment: What added value would your app bring, given that the OSes do these things already?

Comment: Do you honestly think that anyone can explain this in a SO post? The question is way too broad and off-topic for SO

Comment: Basically, this app will take care of printing when it receives a request from web client to print document (s), and send notification back to web client about the undergoing process be it start of printing, finished off printing etc.

Comment: @SakoBu I understand it's such a broad topic, I just want to know if there are some libraries I can check out, or which direction should I go to solve there problem, or any references that can help. I've been searching for it but didn't found anything concrete.